# How important is optimization?

Tags: optimization

I got into a bit of a debate yesterday with my boss about the proper role of optimization when building software. Essentially, his position was that optimization needs to be a primary concern during the entire process of development.

My opinion is that you need to make the right algorithmic decisions during development, but you should never be counting cycles during development. In fact, I feel so strongly about this I had to walk away from the conversation. I've seen too many bad programming decisions in the name of "optimization", and too much bad code defended with the excuse "this way is faster".

What does the StackOverflow.com community think?

Comment: No need to get hot under the collar with your boss. You only need to say this is your real hands-on experience, which always trumps preconceived ideas. And besides, IMO, there's nothing more awful than people agreeing 100% on everything.

Comment: This is one of those debates where more times then not people are just talking past one another.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah, like politics & religion. One way to say something that nobody can argue with is to say "I think XYZ" or "In my opinion XYZ", rather than just "XYZ". The fact that you hold the opinion is indisputable.

Comment: Somewhere between very important and not important at all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

- Donald Knuth

Comment: I still think it's more of an 80/20 ratio

Comment: @Robert: I think that depends largely on what you consider an optimization vs. just smart design.

Comment: I think Knuth should get the rep.

Comment: +1 for the quote in its entirety and not just the head-in-the-sand "premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 15):

I think the premature optimization quote is used by too many to avoid thinking about the hard stuff concerning how well the application will run. I guarantee the users want you to think about how to design it so it will run as fast as possible.

This is not to say you should be timing everything, but the design phase is the easiest place to optimize and not cost lots of time later.

There are often several ways to do anything, you should pick in the design phase the one which is most likely to perform the best (if it turns out to be one of the times when it isn't the best, then optimize later). This should trump the need to have easy to read code.

If you aren't considering performance in the design phase, you aren't going to have a well designed system. That doesn't mean it should be the only concern (although in a database I'd rate it as 3rd in importance, right after data integrity and security), but trying to fix a system where poorly performing techniques were used throughout because the developers thought they were easier to understand is a nightmare. Being a user of such a system where you have to wait for minutes everytime you want to move from one screen to another is a nightmare (developers reallly should spend all day everyday for at least a week, using their systems!) for everyone who is stuck with the badly designed system. It costs less to design properly  than to fix later and considering performance is critical to designing properly.

I work somewhere where the orginal developers drank the koolaid about premature optimization and did everything the way they thought was simplest (but which in almost every case was the wrong choice from a performance perspective). Now we are at 10 times the size we were three years ago and every screen on every website takes 30 seconds or so to load (or worse times out) and we are losing customers because of it. But changing it will be too hard because at the base they designed the database without considering how it would perform and redesigning a database with many many gigabytes of data into a new structure is way too time consuming and costly. If it had been designed to perform from the start it would be both easier to maintain and faster for the clients. We aren't talking about the need to performance tune the top 10 slowest queries here, we are talking about the fact that the overall structure requires a drastic change (one that would affect virtually every query against the system) to perform well.

Yes don't do micro optimization until you nmeed to, but please do the macro stuff. Consider if is this the best way before you commit to the path. Don't write cursors to hit tables with millions of records when a set-based statement will do. Don't try to have as few tables as possible becasue that seems to be a more elegant solution when the tables are storing disparate items (such as people, places, and vehicles) causing every single query to hit the same table and causing every delete to check all sorts of foreign key tables that will not ever have a record for that type of entity (it takes minutes to delete one record from the main table in our database, it's a real joy when something goes wrong in an import (bad data from a client usually) and we have to delete 200,000 let me tell you).

Answer (score 8):

Optimization is almost tautologically a tradeoff: you gain runtime efficiency at the cost of other things (readability, maintainability, flexibility, compile times, etc.).  As such, it's really never a good idea to do unless you know what the tradeoff is and why it's worthwhile.

Even worse, thinking about "how do I do X fast" can be very distracting.  To much energy in that direction can easily lead to you misisng out on method Y which is much better (and often faster --- this is how "optimization" can make your code slower).  Particularly if you do too much of this on a big project from the beginning, it represents a lot of momentum.  If you can't afford to overcome that momentum, you can easily become locked into a bad design because you can't afford the time to restructure it.  This way lie dragons

What your boss may be thinking of is more of an issue of writing bad code via inappropriate representations and algorithms.  It's not really the same thing as optimizing, but an approach where you pay no attention whatsoever to appropriate data structures etc. can result in a codebase that is slow everywhere, and (much like the above "lock in") requires heroic effort to fix.

In general though, premature optimization really honestly is a terrible idea.  Particularly when you end up with a complex, finely tuned, well documented (because that's the only way you can understand it) piece of code you end up not using anyway.  And that's not even getting into the issue of subtle bugs that are often introduced when "optimizing"

[edit:  pshaw, of course a Knuth quote encapsulates this well.  That's what I get for typing too much]

Answer (score 5):

Engineer throughout, optimize at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Since with going with pithy, I'll say that optimization is as important as the impact of not doing it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the "premature optimization is root of all evil" has to be understood literally - it does not say when is premature, and does not say you should optimize only at the end. Just not too early. Also, the "use the right algorithm, O(n^2) vs O(N)" is a bit dangerous if taken literally - because for many problems, the N is actually small, etc...

I think it depends a lot of the type of software you are doing: some software are such as every part is very independent, and can be optimized separately. But that's not always the case. For many (most ?) applications, speed just does not matter at all, the brute force but obviously correct way is the best one. But for projects where speed matters, it often has to be taken into account early - maybe that's another possible interpretation of Knuth's saying: many applications don't need to be optimized at all, just know which ones need and plan ahead.

Answer (score 3):

Optimization is a primary concern through development when you have a good reason to expect that performance will be unfixably bad if optimization is a secondary concern.

This depends a lot what kind of code you're writing, but there are often better reasons to believe that your code will be unfixably difficult to use; or maintain; or full of bugs; or late; if all those things become secondary to tweaking performance.

Bad managers say, "all of those things are our primary concerns". Good managers work to find out which are dangers for this project.

Of course, good design does have to consider all these things, and the earlier you have a back-of-the-envelope estimate of any of them, the better. If all your manager is saying, is that if you never think about how fast your code will run then too much of your code will be dog-slow, then he's right. I just wouldn't say that makes optimization your "primary" concern.

If the USP of your software is that it's faster than your competitors', then optimization is a primary concern. With experience, you can often predict what sorts of operations will be the bottlenecks, design those with optimization in mind right from the start, and more-or-less ignore optimization elsewhere. A lot of projects won't even need this: they'll be fast enough without much effort, provided you use sensible algorithms and don't do anything stupid. "Don't do anything stupid" is always a primary concern, with no need to mention performance in particular.

Answer (score 1):

I think that code needs to be, first and foremost, readable and understandable. So, optimisations that are done, should not be at the expense of readability. However, optimisation is often a trade-off.

Whether or not you should optimise your code depends on your application domain. If you are working on an embedded processor with only 8Mb of memory, then optimisation is probably something that every team member needs to keep in mind, when writing code - optimising for space vs speed.

However, pre-mature optimisation is not useful unless your system has been clearly spec'ed and understood. This is because most programmers do not make good optimisation decisions unless they can factor in the influence of the overall system, including processor architectural factors such as cache memory, hardware threads, pipelines, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From 2 years of building highly optimized Java code (and that *needed* to be optimized that way) I would say that there is a time-spent rule that governs optimization:

- optimizing on the spot: 5%-10% of your development time, because you have to do it countless times (every single time you have to amend your design)
- optimizing just when you have had it working: 2% of your development time (you do it only once)
- going back to it and optimizing when it's too slow: 30% of your development time, because you have to plunge yourself back into the system

SO I would come to the conclusion that there is a right time and a right way to optimize: do it entity by entity (class by class, if you have classes that have a single, well defined job to do, and can be tested and optimized), test well, make sure the logic is working, optimize just afterward, and forget about that entity's implementation details forever.

Answer (score 1):

1. When developing, just *keep it simple*. IMHO, most performance problems are caused by over-engineering - making mountains out of molehills, often because of wanting "the right algorithm".
2. Periodically, stress test with a big data set, profiling or (my favorite technique) manual random sampling. You find a problem, you fix it. You find another, you fix it.

That way you avoid creating slugs (slowness bugs), and when they do arise, you kill them.

Added: If I can just elaborate on point 1. OO is seemingly the law of the land, and it certainly has good reasons behind it. Unfortunately it causes many young programmers to feel that programming is all about having lots of data structure, with layers upon layers of abstraction. Not that those are inherently bad, but combine that with the natural tendency to assume that the time something takes is roughly proportional to the number of characters you have to type to invoke it, and that this tendency multiplies over the layers (and besides, the machines are really fast), it's easy to create a perfect storm of cycle-waste.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from a friend:  "It's easier to make a working system efficient than to make an efficient system work".

I think it is important to use smart practices and patterns from the start, but get the system actually running for small test cases then do performance analysis.  Frequently the areas of code that have poor performance aren't anticipated at the beginning, so get some real data and then optimize the bottlenecking 3% (or 20%, or whatever it is).

Answer (score 1):

I think your boss is a lot more right than you are.

Allt too often the user experience is lost only to be "rediscovered" at the last possible moments when performance activites are prohibitively costly and inefficient. Or when it is discovered that the batch program that will process today's transactions requires forty hours to run.

Things such as database organization, when and when not to do which SELECTs are examples of design decisions that can make or break an application. Still you run the risk of a single programmer deciding to to otherwise, misinterpret or simply not understand what to do. Following-up on performance during an entire project decreases the risk that such things will happen. It also allows design decisions to be changed when there is a need for that without puting the entire poroject at risk.

"You need to make the right algorithmic decisions during development" is certainly true yet how many mainstream programmers are able to do that? Browsing the net for information does not guarantee finding a high quality solution. "Right" could be interpreted as meaning that it is ok to choose a poor algorithm because it is easy to understand and implement (= less development time, lower cost) than a more complicated one (= more development time, higher cost).

The pendulum of quantity vs quality is almost always on the quantity side because more code per hour or faster development time means money in the short term. The quality side means money in the long term.

**EDIT**

[This article](http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1147993) discusses performance and optimization quite thoroughly.

Performance preacher Rico Mariana [sums it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649527.aspx) in the short statement "never give up your performance accidentally."

Answer (score 0):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil...There is a fine balance between, but I would say 95% of the time you need to optimize at the end; however, there are decisions you can make early on to help prevent issues. For example assume we are talking about an e-commerce web site. You have a requirement to display the catalog. Now you can grab all 100,000 items and display 50 of them, or you can grab just 50 from the database. These type of decisions should be made up front.

Cycle counting should only be done when a problem has been identified.

Answer (score 0):

Your boss is partly right, optimisation does need to be considered throughout the development lifecycle but it is rarely the primary concern. Also, the term 'optimisation' is vague - it's an adjective, 'optimise for ...' which could be 'memory', 'speed', 'usability', 'maintainability' and so on.

However, the OP is right that counting cycles is pointless for many projects. For most PC applications the CPU is never the bottleneck. Also, the IA32 is not consistent - what worked well on one architecture, performs poorly on another. Cycle counting should only ever be done when it will actually make a difference - usually in CPU limited code or code with very specific timing needs.

Optimisation, of any kind, must always be driven by hard evidence. Never assume anything about the system or how the code is behaving. In an ideal world, application performance / constraints will be specified in the initial product design and tools to monitor the application's performance during development will be added early on in the development phase to guide the programmers as the product is made.